Drivetrain Compatibility 105 and sora/ tiagra
I want to build 11 speed bike. Could I use an 11-speed cassette with an 11-speed 105 rear derailleur and a Sora/Tiagra crankset with a 105 front derailleur?

Yes. Typically you can utilize a front drive train that is +/-1 speed class away from the rear speeds and have it function completely normal.  You don't mention the shifter's you'd like to use, but they should be Shimano 11 speed shifters.  In addition, the 11 speed road cassette is longer/wider than the speed classes before it. This means that your rear wheel should be equipped with an 11 speed HG Freehub body.  You can check this by measuring the splined portion of the freehub body. An 11 speed body will measure just shy of 37mm (36.85 would be a correct caliper reading in mm's).
Because the rear drivetrain will be 11 speed, you should use an 11 speed chain. It's always best to begin a new cassette's life coupled with a new chain.  Get a new chain when the current chain is 0.5% elongated.  A chain checker will have this figure stamped in it.  Typically, a cassette will last through 3 chain lifetimes if they are changed out before they are overly worn.
It may be best to utilize a Tiagra crankset if you have a choice. Sora is a 9 speed system, which puts you over the +/-1 conventional wisdom, for one. For two, front drivetrains tend to have narrower gaps between chainrings as the speed class increases. It's rare but possible, the 11 speed chain, overall narrower than a nine speed chain, could fall into the wider gap between chainrings of a 9 speed crankset and become jammed.  The same could happen with a 10 speed crankset, but since the phenomenon is rare to begin with it's even less likely here. Best to worry about the quality of shifting and being noise free at the rear drivetrain by using the 11 speed chain on the 11 speed cassette.

I've successfully used a front triple setup from a 15 speed (3x5) with 9 speed rear end.  It "works" but probably only because tolerances were wider back when chains were also, wider.

It may work, but it is outside of the intended purpose and compatibility. You may run into unforeseen problems.
To be perfectly safe, I would strongly advise to adhere to the official Shimano compatibility specifications. Only then will you know it is tested, and you can be sure your bike will have the expected performance, reliability, and safety.
Personally, it's something I would not make compromises on.
